# A weak-type submartingale inequality

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

> Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a submartingale or a supermartingale.
>   Show that, for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\lambda>0$,
>
> $$\lambda P[|X|^*_n\ge \lambda ]\le 12 E[|X_0|]+9E[|X_n|].$$

This problem comes from [Klenke's probability textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144715360X) (11.1.1), and follows the section on Doob's inequalities and Doob's decomposition. We define

$$X^*_n = \sup\{X_k : k\le n\}.$$

**My thoughts:** For simplicity, consider just the case where $X_n$ is a submartingale. Then we can write $X_n=M_n+A_n$, where $M_n$ is a martingale and $A_n$ is an increasing predictable process (so a positive submartingale). Then

$$P[|X|^*_n\ge \lambda ] \le P[|A|^*_n+|M|_n^*\ge \lambda ] \le P[|M|_n^*\ge a\lambda ]+ P[|A|^*_n\ge (1-a)\lambda ],$$

where $a$ will be chosen later. Combining this with the inequality

$$\lambda P[|Y|^*_n\ge \lambda ]\le E[|Y_n|]$$

(which applies with $Y_n$ is a martingale or positive submartingale) gives a bound in terms of $A_n$ and $M_n$, which is not quite what we want. We need a bound in terms of $|X_0|$ and $|X_n|$. I am unable to proceed and would appreciate any help.

Comment: what does $\vert . \vert^*_n$ mean?

Comment: @roger I have edited an answer into my question (under the problem statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that it suffices to consider the case when $X$ is a submartingale since if $X$ is a supermartingale then $-X$ is a submartingale.

To finish your proof, use the following bounds:
$$E[|A_n|] = E[A_n] = E[X_n - M_n] = E[X_n] - E[M_n] = E[X_n] - E[M_0] = E[X_n] - E[X_0] \leq E[|X_n|] + E[|X_0|]$$
and 
$$E[|M_n|] = E[|X_n-A_n|] \leq E[|X_n|] + E[|A_n|] \leq 2 E[|X_n|] + E[|X_0|].$$

Comment: Wouldn't this make the coefficient of $E[|X_n|]$ larger than the coefficient of $E[|X_0|]$? But in the problem statement, it is the other way around.

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't this prove something stronger than what the problem wants?

Comment: @Potato: the bound in the statement of the problem is not optimal.

Comment: I see. That was the source of my confusion. I was trying to choose $a$ to get a 12 or a 9 to appear! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I actually think the following bound holds: $\lambda P(|X|^*_n \geq \lambda) \leq 2E(|X_n|) + E(|X|_0)$. But the proof requires more work.

Comment: I know this question is old but I'm having trouble understanding how to finish this problem. Going through these calculations I'm still ending up with a $\lambda P\left[ A_n \geq (1-a)\lambda\right]$ term, which I know is equal to $\lambda P\left[X_0 - M_0 \geq (1-a)\lambda\right]$. So I've been able to show $$\lambda P \left[|X|_n^* \geq \lambda\right] \leq \frac 1 a \left(2E\left[|X_n|\right] + E\left[|X_0|\right]\right) + \lambda P\left[X_0 - M_0 \geq (1-a)\lambda\right]$$ Is there a way to get rid of this last term?

Comment: @DFord $A_n$ is a positive submartingale so just use Doob's $L^p$ inequality on it.