# A corollary of Doob's inequality for general submartingales

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, martingales

I have been trying to prove the following result:

> Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N_0}$ be a submartingale or supermartingale. Use Doob's Inequality and Doob's Decomposition to show that, for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\lambda > 0$,
> $$
> \lambda\mathbb P\left[|X|_n^* \geq \lambda\right] \leq 12\mathbb E\left[\left|X_0\right|\right] + 9\mathbb E\left[\left|X_n\right|\right].
> $$
> where $|X|_n^* = \sup\left\{|X_k| : 0 \leq k \leq n\right\}$.

The version of Doob's inequality we're using is that for any $p \geq 1$, $\lambda > 0$, and martingale or positive submartingale $Y$,
$$
\lambda^p \mathbb P\left[|Y|_n^*\geq \lambda\right] \leq \mathbb E\left[\left|Y_n\right|^p\right].
$$
It suffices to prove this result when $X$ is a submartingale. Using Doob's decomposition $X = M+A$, $M$ a martingale and $A$ an increasing predictable process with $A_0 = 0$ (so $A$ is a positive submartingale), one can in fact show a stronger inequality. Indeed, since $A$ is positive and increasing, $|X|_n^* \leq |M|_n^* + A_n$. And since $A_0 = 0$:
$$
\mathbb E\left[A_n\right] = \mathbb E\left[X_n\right] - \mathbb E\left[M_n\right] = \mathbb E\left[X_n\right] - \mathbb E\left[M_0\right] = \mathbb E\left[X_n\right] - \mathbb E\left[X_0\right] \leq \mathbb E\left[|X_n|\right] + \mathbb E\left[|X_0|\right]
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left|M_n\right|\right] \leq \mathbb E\left[\left|X_n\right|\right] + \mathbb E\left[A_n\right] \leq 2\mathbb E\left[\left|X_n\right|\right] + \mathbb E\left[\left|X_0\right|\right].
$$
Using these inequalities, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\lambda\mathbb P\left[|X|^*_n\geq \lambda\right] & \leq \lambda\mathbb P\left[|M|_n^*+A_n\geq\lambda\right] \\ &\leq \lambda \mathbb P\left[ |M|^*_n\geq \frac 2 3 \lambda\right] + \lambda\mathbb P\left[A_n\geq\frac 1 3 \lambda\right] \\
&\leq \frac 3 2 \mathbb E\left[\left|M_n\right|\right]+ 3\mathbb E\left[A_n\right] \\
&\leq 6\mathbb E\left[\left|X_n\right|\right]+\frac 9 2 \mathbb E\left[\left|X_0\right|\right]
\end{align*}
My question is twofold:

1. Is there an error in this argument, such as a flaw in my assumptions or an unjustified assumption I'm not noticing? And if not,
2. Is there a reason the book I'm using (Klenke's *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course*) uses the coefficients $12$ and $9$ rather than $9/2$ and $6$? Is the stated result somehow more classical or easier to show using more fundamental properties of martingales and the Doob decomposition?

This problem was also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645382/a-weak-type-submartingale-inequality), but this thread doesn't really address the seeming arbitrariness of the coefficients $12$ and $9$. Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a fragment of an answer because I don't touch upon your proof or the techniques it uses, but it is too long for a comment. My intuition is that the coefficients are arbitrary because they are not optimal. Here is one possible improvement, which I take from the book *Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus* by Jean-François Le Gall (p.263)

> **Maximal inequality** *If  $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a supermartingale then for all $\lambda>0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$:
> $$\lambda\mathbb{P}\left[\sup_{n\leq k}\left|Y_n\right|>\lambda\right]\leq\mathbb{E}\left|Y_0\right|+2\mathbb{E}\left|Y_k\right|$$*

**Proof (not in the book).** Fix $\lambda>0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $A_k=\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \sup_{n\leq k}Y_k(\omega)> \lambda\right\}$. Define the stopping time $T=\inf\left\{n\in\mathbb{N} : Y_n> \lambda\right\}$, and notice that $A_k=\left\{T\leq k\right\}$. Since $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a supermartingale
$$\mathbb{E}Y_0\geq\mathbb{E}Y_{T\land k}\geq \lambda \mathbb{P}(A_k)+\mathbb{E}[Y_k\mathbf{1}_{A_k^c}]$$
Now, let $S=\inf\left\{n\in\mathbb{N} : Y_n<-\lambda\right\}$ and $B_k=\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \inf_{n\leq k} Y_k(\omega)<-\lambda\right\}$. We have
$$\mathbb{E}Y_k\leq\mathbb{E}Y_{S\land k}\leq -\lambda \mathbb{P}(B_k)+\mathbb{E}[Y_k\mathbf{1}_{B_k^c}]$$
Rearranging and summing the two inequalities gives
$$\lambda\mathbb{P}\left[\sup_{n\leq k}\left|Y_n\right|>\lambda\right]\leq \mathbb{E}Y_0-\mathbb{E}[Y_k\mathbf{1}_{A^c_k}]-\mathbb{E}[Y_k\mathbf{1}_{B_k}]\leq \mathbb{E}|Y_0|+2\mathbb{E}|Y_k|$$
By the way, we also proved that an even better upper bound is $\mathbb{E}Y_0 + 2\mathbb{E}Y_k^-$.